# Avoid calling move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have following example

```
#include <cstdint>

class FooC
{
public:
   FooC(uint16_t iPort, uint16_t iPin)
   : PORT(iPort)
   , PIN(iPin)
   {
   };

   ~FooC() = default;

   FooC() = delete;
   FooC(const FooC&) = delete;
   FooC(FooC&&) = delete;

private:
   const uint16_t PORT;
   const uint16_t PIN;
};

int main()
{
    FooC array[2] = {
       FooC(1,2),
       FooC(3,4)
    };
}
```

and I don't want to call the default, move and copy constructor. Due to that I deleted the functions. Unfortunately this results in following error (compiled with C++11)

> : In function 'int main()':
>
> :28:5: error: use of deleted function 'FooC::FooC(FooC&&)'
>
> ```
>  };
>
>  ^
> ```
>
> :16:4: note: declared here
>
> ```
> FooC(FooC&&) = delete;
>
> ^~~~
> ```
>
> :28:5: error: use of deleted function 'FooC::FooC(FooC&&)'
>
> ```
>  };
>
>  ^
> ```
>
> :16:4: note: declared here
>
> ```
> FooC(FooC&&) = delete;
>
> ^~~~
> ```
>
> Compiler returned: 1

Is it possible to force in this example the calling of constructor with the parameters and still delete the default, move and copy constructor?

Comment: use C++17 :-)...

Comment: Since you've deleted default copy and move constructors (as well as assignment oprators) your class is no longer movable and copyable, when your program expecting move assignable class.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `=`

Comment: And `constexpr FooC(uint16_t iPort, uint16_t iPin) noexcept`

Comment: Note that you don't need to delete the move-constructor: when you delete the copy-constructor, the move-constructor is not implicitly generated

Answer (score 14):

In C++11 and C++14, you can use nested braces:

```
FooC array[2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

In C++17 your code should already work as written thanks to the new prvalue/materialization rules ("guaranteed copy elision").

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to force in this example the calling of constructor with the parameters and still delete the default, move and copy constructor?

No with your current syntax (before C++17) and yes (in C++17).

**Pre-C++17:**

This is not possible.  The aggregate initialization copies the initializers into the aggregate.  This means you have to have an accessible copy/move constructor.  In C++11 you have to pass the constructor parameters as their own *braced-init-list*.  This means you aren't copying `FooC`'s but instead copy-list-initializing the `FooC`'s in the array which calls the 2 parameter constructor instead of the copy/move constructor.

```
FooC array[2] = {
   {1, 2},
   {3, 4}
};
```

**C++17:**

You no longer have temporary objects in the *braced-init-list* and each element of the array will be directly initialized instead of copy initialized.

Comment: I'd be careful with the phrasing here. Your pre-C++17 example is copy-list-initializing the elements.

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible.

What you can do is **don't** mention these lines :

```
FooC() = delete;
FooC(const FooC&) = delete;
FooC(FooC&&) = delete;
```

So, now your code only will have default destructor. The compiler will not generate any move constructor or move assignment operator as destructor is defined(default).
This is surpass your error, and