# Avoid calling default, move and copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++17

I have following example (extension to [Avoid calling move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53381152/7200859))

```
#include <cstdint>

class Interface
{
public:
   Interface() = default;
   virtual ~Interface() = default;
   Interface(const Interface&) = delete;
   Interface(Interface&&) = delete;
   const Interface& operator=(const Interface&) = delete;
   Interface& operator=(Interface&&) = delete;
};

class FooC : public Interface
{
public:
   FooC(uint16_t iPort, uint16_t iPin)
   : PORT(iPort)
   , PIN(iPin)
   {
   };

   FooC() = delete;
   ~FooC() override = default;
   FooC(const FooC&) = delete;
   FooC(FooC&&) = delete;
   const FooC& operator=(const FooC&) = delete;
   FooC& operator=(FooC&&) = delete;

private:
   const uint16_t PORT;
   const uint16_t PIN;
};

class FactoryC
{
public:
   FactoryC()
   : mFoo{
     {1, 2},
     {3, 4}
   }
   {
   };

   ~FactoryC() = default;
   FactoryC(const FactoryC&) = delete;
   FactoryC(FactoryC&&) = delete;
   const FactoryC& operator=(const FactoryC&) = delete;
   FactoryC& operator=(FactoryC&&) = delete;

private:
   FooC mFoo[2];
};

int main()
{
    FactoryC factory{};
}
```

and I don't want to call the default, move and copy constructor. Due to that I deleted the functions. Unfortunately this results in following error (compiled with C++17)

```
<source>: In constructor 'FactoryC::FactoryC()':

<source>:42:4: error: use of deleted function 'FooC::FooC(FooC&&)'

    }

    ^

<source>:26:4: note: declared here

    FooC(FooC&&) = delete;

    ^~~~

Compiler returned: 1
```

Is it possible to force in this example the calling of constructor with the parameters and still delete the default, move and copy constructor of FooC?

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/ax8I1F

Comment: Fwiw, msvc 19 (vs2015) chews this up without issue.

Comment: @bolov error happens with gcc 8.2. Might be a bug.

Comment: This certainly looks like a bug. Making `Interface` destructor non-virtual (with corresponding removal of override) fixes compilation issue.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug. @SergeyA's comment:

> This certainly looks like a bug. Making Interface destructor non-virtual (with corresponding removal of override) fixes compilation issue.

suggests that the issue has to do with virtual base classes. Indeed, [bug report #86849](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86849) deals with an unrelated issue and Richard Smith comes to this conclusion:

> Interestingly, GCC does appear to suppress guaranteed copy elision if the class has virtual base classes.

Comment: There's no virtual base class in OP's code. There is a non-virtual base class with a virtual destructor

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the bug a providing a interim solution :-)